# How to connect QDBusConnection signal

Tags: qt, signals-slots, dbus

I have connected my `QDBusConnection` to a slot and I am sure it is connected because connect functions return True and i can see "**connected to slot**" log on console.

```
if ( m_bus.connect("com.mypage.MyService"
        , "/MyRadio"
        , "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
        , "PropertiesChanged"
        , this
        , SLOT(updateProperties(QString, QMap<QString, QVariant>))
                  )) {
        qWarning() << "connected to slot";
    }
```

But i cannot get any updates from corresponding dbus service. I am watching the service with dbus-monitor and am sure about signal is emitting.

the signal has following type :

```
      <signal name="PropertiesChanged">
          <arg type="s" name="interface_name"/>
          <arg type="a{sv}" name="changed_properties"/>
          <arg type="as" name="invalidated_properties"/>
      </signal>
```

If i add a third argument to Slot like `QList<QString>` then it cannot connect properly ("connected the slot" sentence cannot be seen).

Any clue about why this is not working properly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has solved after adding

```
qDBusRegisterMetaType<QMap<QString, QVariant>>();
```

So it was a simple error afterall.